# Slic3r - how to combine specific perl code with Slic3r SupportMaterial.pm?

Tags: 3d-models, g-code, slicing, support-structures, scripts

I've got a specific perl support tree script that I would like to integrate into Slic3r. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be more about programming than it is about 3D printing. Modifying a slicer's code is well outside the scope of this stack, I'm afraid.